# Display text over Canvas only onmouseover

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have created a triangle shaped image mask with the Canvas element. I have a field of text which I want to display at the bottom line of this triangle when mouse over. I can´t figure out how to make the text display only when hovering.

I am a beginner at this... Any help appriciated!

This is the code I got so far:

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <a href="#"><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas></a>
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
function masks() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        draw(ctx,img,"Hello!");
    }
    img.src="canvas01.png";
    function draw(ctx,img,text){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);            
        ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.closePath();                                          
        ctx.clip();                        
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        if(text){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#f30";
            ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-20,canvas.width,20);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.font="14pt Verdana";
            var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
            ctx.fillText(text,(canvas.width-textWidth)/2,canvas.height-3); 
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: For a quick and simple text hover you may also set the canvas element title attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how...

You can draw your text when the user's mouse is over the canvas element using:

```
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
            draw(ctx,img,"Hello!");
        });
```

You can clear the text when the user's mouse has moved outside the canvas element using:

```
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            draw(ctx,img);
        });
```

Note that your draw function now clears the canvas in preparation for redrawing:

```
    function draw(ctx,img,text){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);            
        ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.closePath();                                          
        ctx.clip();                        
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        if(text){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#f30";
            ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-20,canvas.width,20);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.font="14pt Verdana";
            var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
            ctx.fillText(text,(canvas.width-textWidth)/2,canvas.height-3);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Q4TKC/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid lightgray;}
</style>

<script>
window.onload=function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        canvas.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
            draw(ctx,img,"Hello!");
        });
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            draw(ctx,img);
        });

        draw(ctx,img);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sky-bg2.jpg";


    function draw(ctx,img,text){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);            
        ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.closePath();                                          
        ctx.clip();                        
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        if(text){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#f30";
            ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-20,canvas.width,20);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.font="14pt Verdana";
            var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
            ctx.fillText(text,(canvas.width-textWidth)/2,canvas.height-3);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

};  // end window.onload

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh I see! Now I know the addEventListener! Thanks again:) If I want to have transition effect on the pop up field, is that possible? @markE

Comment: Also I see the edges on the triangle is now a little pixeled which was not there before. Not a big issue but do you know why?

Comment: Yes, as Ken says, pixilation is due to clipping. Also, referring to your previous question on this same subject...Here's how to wire up multiple canvas's with hoverable triangles: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jrTs2/

Comment: Thank you for all your help!!! I have been trying to wire up different pictures instead of 3 of the same but not getting that to work either. Thought I would change something in the "//load image section...". And also trying to make a transition effect on the pop up field so it shows a little smoother. @markE

Comment: Here’s a link to a Fiddle that shows how to pre-load your multiple images and how to apply a fade-in “transition” effect on your text labels:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6UKxL/