# Display HTML text annotation on click of three.js geometry?

Tags: three.js

I would like to add 2d text annotations to a 3d object similar to [this](https://sketchfab.com/models/d82bea156a1c4176b5d09b82b176e84c).

I haven't found any tutorials on overlaying a 3d object with HTML elements that can be turned off and on with click. I did find this but wasn't sure if there was another way other than rendering to the canvas.
[Display text over Canvas only onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539492/display-text-over-canvas-only-onmouseover)

Seems like I should be able to toggle display styles of absolute-positioned elements, but I can't figure it out. Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: Canvas is an HTML element like any other. You can create other HTML elements next to it and place it over it by using position:absolute in CSS. And you can hide/show these elements using the display attribute in CSS. What exactly is your question? Handling a click on a canvas or displaying a HTML element over canvas or hiding/showing an HTML element or positioning the HTML element?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since I'm clicking on points on a dynamic, rotatable 3d model and not fixed coordinates on the canvas I wasn't sure I could render text outside of the canvas environment. I guess what I can't figure out is how to communicate a click on a three.js object to an html element. I apologize if my explanation is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot tutorials to determine the object when clicking on the canvas (using raycaster and projection). Basically, you want it the other way round: having a 3D coordinate and want to get the 2D coordinate above the canvas where you can postion a html element.

I would do it the following way:

1. Html structure

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div id="tip" style="position: absolute; display: none">Some text</div>
</div>
```

2. Determine the clicked object

```js
var selectedObject;

// using jquery
$('canvas').on('click', function(event) {

  // get 2D viewport coordinates
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  mouse.x = (event.offsetX / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - (event.offsetY / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;

  // raycast
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5).unproject(camera);
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(arrayOfObjects, true);

  if(intersects.length > 0 ) {
    selectedObject = intersects[0].object;

    // toggle html element
    $('#tip').css('display', 'block');
    $('#tip').text(selectedObject.userData.note);

    // assuming that the actual position is at the center of the mesh, otherwise the text will display somewhere else
    // alternatively you could store and pass the point of click: intersects[0].point
    positionTip(selectedObject.position);
  }

});
```

3. position the html element (if you manipulate the camera, then you need to call this each time, so the element's position will update too)

```js
function positionTip(pos3D) {

  var v = pos3D.project(camera);
  var left = SCREEN_WIDTH * (v.x + 1) / 2;
  var top = SCREEN_HEIGHT * (-v.y + 1) / 2;

  $('#tip').css({ left: left, top: top });

}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I cannot guarantee that these code snippets work out of the box. I just copied some pieces of code from my project and made some additions/modifications for generalisation.

Comment: Thank you! That points me in the right direction with raycaster